# Encrypt traffic between squid and clients

Tags: linux, proxy, ssh, squid

I got a squid 2.8 running on an ubuntu 10.04LTS server. 
I've build it with "ssl support", but I am not sure what that means. 
The problem is that I am using the proxy to access a torrent site, however when I try to download the .torrent file it does not work, because my ISP is running some kind of shaper, which does not allow me download it. 
The problem however disappears if I do a

```
ssh -D localhost:port remote_server
```

And set the Mozilla proxy to localhost.

if there a way to achieve this with squid.

Answer (score 0):

"ssl support" means that Squid will be able to listen and open SSL. This is used in reverse proxy configuration usually but can be used in forward proxies. Not all browsers support SSL connections to proxies, only Chrome I think.

If you want to do something simple, use the command that you wrote and then fill ONLY the SOCKS field with localhost and port. Leave other fields blank. You don't need a proxy in this setup, only a remote server and SSH command.

Regards,
 Diego

Comment: What I am trying to avoid is exactly that -> having to open up a socks proxy .....